# Get list of ZSH commands from ~/.zsh_history with regex separator and multiline fields

Tags: awk, sed, grep, regular-expression

I want to get a list of all commands from the ZSH history in ~/.zsh_history.  The file is formatted like so:

```
: 1467892191:0;cd /usr/share
: 1467892276:0;lsrc
: 1467892743:0;logout
: 1467892751:0;reload
: 1484284548:0;echo 'multiple \
line \
test'
```

Commands may span multiple lines.  The initial format is the same for every command, e.g the regex `^: \d{10}:\d;`.

Here's the desired output

```
cd /usr/share
lsrc
logout
reload
echo 'multiple \n line \n test'
```

Any standard Unix command is fair game.  The purpose of this is so I can pass the list of commands to my $EDITOR to for easy selection for documentation or write-ups.

Here's as far as I got with awk, which prints mostly empty lines.

```
awk -F': [0-9]{10}:[0-9];' '{ print $1 }' ~/.zsh_history
```

Comment: `': [0-9]{10}:[0-9];'` is more a record separator than a field separator, here. That said, wouldn't `fc -ln` be easier?

Answer (score -1):

can you try this awk command

```
$ cat a.txt
: 1467892191:0;cd /usr/share
: 1467892276:0;lsrc
: 1467892743:0;logout
: 1467892751:0;reload
: 1484284548:0;echo 'multiple \
line \
test'
: 1467892191:0;cd /usr/share
: 1467892276:0;lsrc
: 1467892743:0;logout
: 1467892751:0;reload
: 1484284548:0;echo 'multiple \
line \
: 1467892751:0;reload


$ awk -F\; 'NF!=1{printf("\n%s",$NF)}NF==1{printf("n %s ",$1)}' a.txt

cd /usr/share
lsrc
logout
reload
echo 'multiple \n line \ n test'
cd /usr/share
lsrc
logout
reload
echo 'multiple \n line \
reload
```